# Two seemingly equal values give FALSE on comparison for equality

Tags: r, comparison

I have two columns containing data. While comparing these columns I got `FALSE` return on this row, which kind of stumped me.

```
dat[82,"UG_accept_avg_total.x"]
## [1] 1.842105
dat[82,"UG_accept_avg_total.y"]
## [1] 1.842105
dat[82,"UG_accept_avg_total.x"]==dat[82,"UG_accept_avg_total.y"]
## [1] FALSE
```

I read the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal) which explained why my problem occurs, but the answer didn't help me a lot because:

```
all.equal(dat[82,"UG_accept_avg_total.x"],dat[82,"UG_accept_avg_total.y"])
## "Mean relative difference: 1.427714e-07"
isTRUE(all.equal(dat[82,"UG_accept_avg_total.x"],dat[82,"UG_accept_avg_total.y"]))
## [1] FALSE
```

I could just shave off some digits after the decimal point, since 3 is probably enough, but checking all data fields (over 250000) in my data set to do this would be a rather wasteful use of recources. Does anyone have a better suggestion? Is there a way to decrease the "sensitivity" of isTRUE(all.equal(x,y))?

Comment: `all.equal` has a `tolerance` argument. Does increasing that work?

Comment: Just goes to show:  reading the help pages actually is useful :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `tolerance` argument in `all.equal`.

This works on my machine:

```
x <- 0.0000001
y <- 0.0000002

isTRUE(all.equal(x, y))
## [1] FALSE

isTRUE(all.equal(x, y, tolerance=10^-7))
## [1] TRUE
```